# How do I add new folders to a Mercurial Repository?

Tags: mercurial

So I have a mercurial repository set up and it would be great if someone can guide me out..

SO, I have a space on the server specific to the work I do. Let say that address of that path is:

```
https://foo.bar/space
```

In that I have a folder called

```
Project/Project_1
```

Now I am working on another project

```
Project_2
```

and I wrote few code..
now How do I create a folder

```
Project/Project_2 on the repo
```

and then push all the changes I want to make

I guess a very trivial question..

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Do you want to **create a new repository** on your server ? Do you want to **add a folder to an existing repository** ? I think you are mixing some terms in your question. You should read some basic documentation about Mercurial first of all, for example http://hginit.com/ ... If you need some help, explain what you are trying to achieve in some "abstract" ways, and someone will "translate" this to mercurial command / terms.

Comment: @krtek Hi.. I think you are right.. Basically I have been given some space to work on various projects on foo.bar/space And now I have started second project.. So rather than changes on one project I want to add this second project on that space and manage it bny mercurial.. Any clues on how to do that? I hope my question is bit clear now. :) Thanks

Comment: The common workflow with Mercurial is to have one different repository (what you call space I think) for each different project. So the basic idea will be to ask for another space. You're saying that you were "given" some space, so maybe you should ask the people who did that to help you ! Your question is really vague and lack a lot of details to provide you with a real answer. You should really read the documentation a provided in my last command, I'm fairly sure all the answer you're looking for are their :) And if you have difficulties, ask a new question with the correct wording.

Comment: @krtek: Hi.. Sorry to bother you again. But what if I just want to add a new folder in the old repo.. So maybe something like.. Project/Project_1/NewProject and maybe for now thats where I can save my files and later migrate it to new repo...how can I do that

Comment: Once again, all the answer are in the documentation :) You should read it... But you can add a new directory, or file for that matter, to your repository with the `hg add` command, and then `commit` and `push` like you would do otherwise. This is no different than any operation you should have done with the previous project.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5447/discussion-between-krtek-and-fraz)

Answer (score 4):

Mercurial doesn't track directories (aka folders) at all.  It tracks **files**.  Just `hg add Project/Project2/yourfilename.ext` and when you `hg commit` and `hg push` you'll see it on "*the server*".  You can add a lot of files at once with `hg addremove` but you still need to commit and push them.

It sounds like you've got a very incomplete understanding of Mercurial and should track down a good introduction (or the free online book) before you take actions you'll regret.

Comment: There is a guide [here](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/file-names-and-pattern-matching.html). It says, "When you provide a directory name, Mercurial will interpret this as “operate on every file in this directory and its subdirectories”. Mercurial traverses the files and subdirectories in a directory in alphabetical order. When it encounters a subdirectory, it will traverse that subdirectory before continuing with the current directory. "

Comment: Also, "In addition to working with file and directory names, Mercurial lets you use patterns to identify files. "

Comment: Furthermore, in this [article](http://hginit.com/00.html), the author says, "The last major conceptual difference between Subversion and Mercurial is not as big a deal, but it will trip you up if you’re not aware of it, and here it is:

Subversion is basically revision control for files, but in Mercurial, revision control always applies to an entire directory—including all subdirectories."

Comment: Yup, all 3 of those are worded such that you're misinterpreting them.  The first is saying "when you ask mercurial to do something w/ a directory it won't, it will instead look at its contents".  The second is saying "in addition to talking about files by their exact name or as part of a group by talking about the directory they're in you can use patterns."  The third is saying "with subversion you can check out separate files at separate revisions, but in mercurial all files in the repository have to be checked out at the same version".